# Need help inserting HTML and canvas data into a MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a little web app where you can draw onto a canvas and leave a comment (using a form submit). Now I just need help sending that data into a MySQL database.

This is a form where the user would input their comment. When they click the "Post" button a function called "boo" runs.

```
<form action="testSave.php" method="post" onsubmit="boo();">
    <div id="canvas-bottom">
        <input type="text" id="comment-box" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"/>
        <input type="submit" id="post-button" name="post" value="Post"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

The "boo" function gets the canvas data and sends it to another PHP file called "testSave.php"

```
<script>
function boo(){
    var canvasData = drawingCanvas.toDataURL();     
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "testSave.php",
      data: { 
         canvasData: canvasData
      }
    })
}
</script>
```

This is the "testSave.php" file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['canvasData'], $_POST['post'])) {
    $img = $_POST['canvasData'];
    $filteredData = substr($img, strpos($img, ",")+1);

    $comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);   
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $comment);

    $sql = "INSERT into posts (sketch, comment) VALUES ('$filteredData', '$comment')";

    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

When this is ran it sends me to it's blank white webpage (/testSave.php), doesn't work.

So with this, im trying to send this data into a mysql database table under "sketch" (where the canvas data would go) and "comment" (where the input data would go) in one single row.

If anyone could help me out on this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Where do you define the parameters of $db?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you defined `$db` which may be the issue, as your code would not know where to insert the data into. As others have said it's also best to use prepared statements.

```
if(isset($_POST['canvasData']) and isset($_POST['post'])) {

$mysqlHost = "";
$mysqlUser = "";
$mysqlPassword = "";
$mysqlDatabase = "";

$db=mysqli_connect($mysqlHost, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPassword, $mysqlDatabase);
$img = $_POST['canvasData'];
$filteredData = substr($img, strpos($img, ",")+1);
$comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT into posts (sketch, comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $filteredData, $comment);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: the $db variable just connects to the database

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to submit using ajax, your code should look this;

HTML

```
 <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="canvas-bottom">
            <input type="text" id="comment-box" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"/><br>
<span id="msg" style="color: green;font-style: italic;"></span> // success message
            <input type="submit" id="post-button" name="post" value="Post"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#post-button").click(function(){
                var name =$("#comment-box").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'testSave.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        name:name
                    },
                   success:function(response){
                       $("#msg").html(response);
                   }
                });
            });
        });
```

PHP (testSave.php)

```
  <?php
        $img = $_POST['canvasData'];
        $filteredData = substr($img, strpos($img, ",")+1);

        $comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);   
        $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $comment);

        $sql = "INSERT into posts (sketch, comment) VALUES ('$filteredData', '$comment')";

        if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
              echo "Inserted successfully";
       } else {
              echo "failed";
       }
    ?>
```